# jQuery no conflict with prototype Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, prototype

I am calling the jQuery library within my custom functions file with Selenium IDE (Selenium uses prototype I believe), haven't had a problem before but a recent update to Firefox seems to have caused an issue. I have found the issue and it stems to this function

```
/* allow use of jQuerys global variable $ */
function _getGlobalVar(varName) {
  var win = selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow();
    if (win[varName]) {
      return win[varName];
    } else {
      throw undefined;
    }
}

/* allows use of Jquery selectors in pages where jQuery is loaded*/
function jQuery(selector) {
  var jq = _getGlobalVar('jQuery');
    if (typeof jq != 'undefined') {
      return jq(selector);
    } else {
      throw new SeleniumError('jQuery is not defined in the current window');
    }
}
```

When I want to use jQuerys trim method in the following function. I have read the docs and I know I can use `jQuery.noConflict();`, but it doesn't seem to be helping

```
Selenium.prototype.doClickSearchTemplate = function (locator, action) {
  $ = _getGlobalVar('jQuery');
  profileToggleButton = null;
  profileName = '';

 var locator = locator || 'id=content';
 var reportBlockContainer = this.page().findElement(locator);

jQuery(reportBlockContainer).find('.reportBlockHeader h2 strong').each(function(index, elem) { 
  profileName = $.trim(jQuery(elem).text());
    if (profileName == action)  
      profileToggleButton = elem.parentNode.previousElementSibling; // previousSibling = jQuery(elem).parent().prev().get(0);
});

  if (profileToggleButton === null)
    throw new SeleniumError("Invalid Search Template Name: " +action);

    this.browserbot.clickElement(profileToggleButton);
};
```

The issue that this causes is that when I click 'play current test case' it will run fine first time, call this function, carry out the function and my test will pass, however when I try and press 'play current test case' again, it is like the button is disabled and it won't fire.

If I don't call this function then everything works fine, I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the assignment of the `$` variable.

Comment: https://github.com/Nthalk/SeleniumJQuery

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by just resorting back to JavaScript

```
profileName = jQuery(elem).text();
profileName = profileName.trim();
```

Everything is fine now